# How to make a tableView that can slide horizontal?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want a tableView that slide horizontal.

Just look like what scrollView can do.

Can I?Thx

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at this [**link**](https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView.git)

```
- (void)easyTableView:(EasyTableView *)easyTableView setDataForView:(UIView *)view forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

By calling the above method you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding `UITableView` in `UIScrollView`. Extend the `UITableView` width how much you want and set `UIScrollView` Content size as same as `UITableView` frame( width and height) in implementation file.Then run your code.I hope this will work.Please let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Thank you very much. The UIScrollView is what I want.:)

Comment: Is my solution worked for you? If so, then please accept the answer.

Comment: where can I press the "accept" button?Sorry I am new here

Comment: there will be a tick symbol just left side to my answer(below the upvote and down vote option).Please click that tick symbol so it comes to enable state(Green colour).

Comment: I don't have that much reputation to do that. Soory~

Comment: You don't need to have reputation to accept the answer.Just below to the up vote option, there will be a tick mark.Just click it.